# How to provide dependency in interdependent classes using dagger

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have two classes like this

```
class A {
    private B b = null;

    A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }

    void fooA() {
        b.calledFromA();
    }

    void calledFromB() {

    }
}
class B {
    private A a;

    B(A a) {

        this.a = a;
    }

    void fooB() {
        a.calledFromB();
    }

    void calledFromA() {

    }
}
```

As we can see class `A` depends on class `B` and vice-versa. I need B's object to call some method in A class. How would I provide dependency using dagger?

Comment: Dagger generates normal code. How would you write code yourself  to do this by hand?

Comment: This code is before applying the dagger. I just wanted to know how can I model these classes using Dagger.

Comment: This is badly designed.  Dagger will be able to create an A for you, but not a B.

Comment: Okay, so what is the solution here means good design. Can you suggest?

Comment: Two interweaved classes like this indicates that they share responsibility and either should be merged into a single class or a third class should be written which is passed both an A and a B.   Note that for dagger to work, you may not create objects with `new` yourself - all must be injected.  I would suggest using constructor injection because that is easier to test.

Comment: Thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I will try to merge both classes into one.